# Get the last used value of the forloop counter

Tags: python, django

I'm using the `forloop` counter to assign unique ids to three  which I later populate with data.

```
    <tbody>
    {% for d in data %}
    <tr>
        <td id="menge{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ d.menge }}</td>
        <td id="preis{{ forloop.counter }}" name="preis">{{ d.preis }}</td>
        <td>{{ d.einheit }}</td>
        <td id="preisprostuekc{{ forloop.counter }}" name="{{ d.id}}">
</td>
</tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
```

Lets say the loop runs 10 times. This means the last assigned value is 10. Can i get that value, the last value of the counter, to reuse it in a javascript function? If yes: how? Thanks!

Comment: Over what do you loop? Can you include the loop?

Comment: sure ;) here you go, i updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if `data` is an iterable where one can call `len(…)` on, you can use this to determine the number of objects, so you can use the [**`|length`** template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#length):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var value = {{ data|length }};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! that's it, even though i read and saw it in the docu, i simply couldn't process it mentally anymore .

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`forloop.last`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/)

Like this:

```
{% for d in data %}
 {% if forloop.last %}
   <div>Last number = {{ forloop.counter }} </div>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```